# Training Spacy NER Model - something is not working

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm a student working on training my very first Named Entity Recognition (NER) model using spaCy, following the tutorial in the official documentation (https://spacy.io/usage/training).

The results by training my model are not satisfactory so I wanted to do hyperparameter search, if it is possible with spaCy.

The model trained on a dataset labeled by hand has a lower accuracy compared to the pretrained model (77% vs 85%). I'm trying to understand why my custom-trained model is not performing as well as expected. To improve the performance, I want to perform a hyperparameter random search. However, I can't seem to update the hyperparameters in the `config.cfg` file. Every time I make changes to the configuration, they get overwritten when I run the training command.

I'd appreciate any guidance or resources on how to address these issues. I'm particularly interested in how to improve the training process and how to successfully update and save the hyperparameters in the spaCy configuration file, and if it can be automated somehow.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!